# row specific class

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

How do I create a Zend_Db_Table which returns a different class for each row.?

Example
UserTable has id,name and type
Type contains class names (admin,client,etc...)

The classes admin, client are all subclasses of user

If I call fetch I need to get a admin or client object depending on the corresponding value in the db.

Comment: I find this question interesting, but I am left wondering what makes it necessary.  It seems that the model should abstract it so you don't need to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Your_Db_Table_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
}

class Your_Db_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_rowClass = "Your_Db_Table_Row";
}
```

or

```
new Your_Db_Table(array("rowClass" => "Your_Db_Table_Row");
```

So whenever you get a rowset from your table subclass, the rows included in it will be your custom class.

**Edit**

To get a custom row based on a value, I would say extend the `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract` class instead and override this method:

```
getRow(int $position, [bool $seek = false])
```

You'll also need to override the `current` method and perhaps some of the other `SeekableIterator` implemetations which actually creates a row class based on the `_rowClass` property. You might be able to set the `_rowClass` before `current` is called based on your data's row type.

You could instantiate a specific class in current and return it based on the type parameter.

Have you though about maybe just using composition instead? Say just passing in data to a new class if it's an admin type or something?

Comment: This will use the 'Your_Db_Table_row' class for each row, it needs to be different depeding on the 'type' field value.

Comment: Very true; I read that question too quickly. Edited with a suggestion.